# Does anyone have a good tutorial for email authentication in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a signup flow based on JWT and would like to add a middle process where, once the user has signed up with an email and password, he is in an intermediary state, until he gets a confirmation email with a custom link and clicks on that link.

I've built similar things with EJS and jQuery, but never in React-Redux. I'm not finding any good tutorials; can anyone recommend such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a combination of Stephen Grider's course as suggested by Asten Miles, and this template: https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/node-redux-auth/tree/master/server/src

Reworked it a bit to use async/await, but overall, it is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise Advanced React and Redux course on Udemy, by Stephen Grider. He's made plenty of great tutorials.

Through this tutorial he will teach you everything you need to know on Redux, authentication and much more.

https://www.udemy.com/react-redux-tutorial/

Regarding the confirmation email see this tutorial https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/handling-transactional-emails-in-react-redux-apps-8b1134748f76

Comment: That is a great course, but it doesn't cover email confirmation at all.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I would have loved to integrate some code in my answer but I'm on my phone. Cheers, hope it helps

Comment: Ended up going with this: https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/node-redux-auth/tree/master/server/src